# Who left the site on May 25?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed a `-255` on my reputations on May 25 due the removal of a user. Apparently, the same reputation drop also happened to many other users who have been around for a while. So the user who left or was removed on May 25 must have been an active member of the community for quite some time and contributed at least by voting a lot (perhaps also by asking/answering many questions).

Just out of curiosity: who was this person? Does anyone know the reason for his/her departure?

Comment: Hey me too! Im checking now

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night

Comment: I am also very annoyed at having lost over 100 reputation over night. I know that's standard stack exchange policy, but I would appreciate it if the mods could bring up with the central site runners our concerns with this policy, especially for struggling new sites still in beta. If my reputation is going to randomly drop like this, it diminishes the motivation to continue answering questions, which is especially problematic for this site.

Comment: It seems that, since this individual was a high-voting member in the community, their votes should remain. After all, "If the user has cast a large number of votes, deletion will be held up so staff may consider preserving the votes prior to the deletion."

Answer (score 5):

For privacy reasons, the departing account and the reasons for departure [won't be shared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328644/164022). If the departing user wants to share those elsewhere, then that's up to them.